# AngularJS: how to load promise into template?

Tags: angularjs, templates, promise

```js
vm.promises = {};

vm.addPromise = function (src) {
  if (!angular.isDefined(vm.promises[src])) {
    vm.promises[src] = $http.get(src).then(function (res) {
      console.log("returning data: " + res.data);
      return res.data;
    });
    console.log("created new promise");
  } else {
    console.log("using existing promise");
  }
  return vm.promises[src];
};

$scope.loadStuff = function (src) {
  console.log("loadStuff " + src);
  return;
  vm.addPromise(src);
};

// ----------------------------------- template:

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  {{loadStuff('stuff.txt')}}
</body>
```

Hi, I'm trying to http-load a simple promise into my template (using Angular 1.3) but there are 2 problems:

1. The loadStuff function gets called multiple times (6 on my chrome, inside plunkr)
2. Even if I reuse the same promise for multiple load-calls, the output is "{}" for some reason although I can see in the log that the data itself was fetched correctly

Note: I cannot use ng-include in my case.

[Here's the plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/hri0PdwYSrkT8ocTaQoz), check out the console log to see what I mean...

Expected output:
some stuff loaded

Actual output:

```
{}
```

How do I get this thing to work?

Comment: you should check out [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource), it sounds like this is what you want

Comment: my issue is not how to get the data - this works. My issue is how to correctly bind it inside the template...

Comment: If you'd read about $resource you'll see it solves the issue of displaying the result of an http-request

Comment: also, you shouldn't call a function from the template, this way it will be called every $digest-cykel (this is what you're seeing with it being called 6 times), you should call it once in the controller for example, and then bind the result to the scope, which you display

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that you are doing wrong:

1. When you assign a promise to a variable like you did in `vm.promises[src] = $http.get(src).then(...`, then that variable is a promise. It does not get populated with what the callback function returns. The correct approach in this case would be something like:

   ```
   $http.get(src).then(function(res) {
     console.log("returning data: " + res.data);
     vm.promises[src] = res.data;
   });
   ```

   This, by it self will give you your desired result ([see here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Cq4elNc6c4kiERyw5hng?p=preview)), but if you open developer tools you'll see terrible things: `stuff.txt` is called loaded multiple times, and eventually angular throws an infinite digest loop error. This is because you call `loadStuff` from the template. See @Gustav's comment above. Which leads us to...
2. You shouldn't mix synchronous calls with async calls. You call `loadStuff` and expect it to behave like a synchronous function and return a value right away, while its implementation is calling an asynchronous function. The correct approach here is to have your controller call the async function once, store the returned value once it resolves, and display the stored value in your template. See a simple example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/CUZRzZmxJHEtBY4o67je?p=preview).

Comment: I was not trying to mix sync and async calls, but rather trying to let the template engine resolve the promise for me. I think it used to work in earlier angular versions...  I guess they dropped it because of an overhaul to the digest engine.

Comment: I don't think this would work in any Angular version... anyway, follow my guidelines and everything should work :)

Comment: again, take a look at $resource. With $resource you put the result of the resource-call directly in the template (but doing the call in the controller). then when the promise of the request is resolved, the resource will populate the template with the data